# Rotate CSS 3D generated cube on drag

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have a 3D generated Cube made with CSS and it rotates perfectly when hovered on.

What I need is to add the draggable function to make it rotate with the mouse.

So far I have this:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ca5gpwcj/)

In order to make the hover work you need to uncomment the following CSS:

```
/*.box-scene:hover .box {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
}*/
```

I use draggable function from JQueryUI to try to make it work but somehow it is not working.

PS: I only need it to rotate on Y Axis.

Any help will be appresiated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I got it working finally.

Apparently the error was that JSFiddle doesn't load external resources if they are requested without SSL.

The code that was loaded initially is actually correct.

The final working fiddle is:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ca5gpwcj/2/)

Final Javascript:

```
var offset = 0, startX;
var elem = document.getElementById("box");
$('#box-scene').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    startX = e.pageX - offset;
})
.on('mouseup', function() {
    startX = null;
})
.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    if(startX) {
        offset = e.pageX - startX;
        elem.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'rotateY(-' + offset + 'deg)';
    }
});
```

Thank you @Andrew and @Armand Maree for your help.

Hope this works for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think draggable is what you want; that widget allows you to move objects around on the page.  It looks like you want to be able to click the mouse and move it, and then see the cube rotate proportionally to how far you've moved the mouse.   I don't know of a way to do *that* in pure CSS, I would suggest javascript similar to the following:

```
var dragging = false;
var originalX;
cube.mouseDown(function(e){
   originalX =  e.pageX;
   dragging = true;
});
cube.mouseUp(function(e){
    dragging = false;
});
cube.mouseMove(function(e){
    if (dragging){
        var DeltaX = e.pageX - originalX;
        var rotation = CalculateRotationDegrees(DeltaX);
        cube.css('transform',rotation);
    }
});
```

In this example, the method CalculateRotationDegrees would take the distance the user has moved the mouse and figure out how far the cube should rotate based on that distance.

Comment: Actually I got the draggable from this example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CxTY6/2/), seeing as it uses draggable to change the properties of -webkit-transform the same as I need it. I will try to implement your javascript and see if it works. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: That fiddle is doing the same thing as the code I gave you, although polished up a bit to get to full functionality.  Notably, it is not using JqueryUI.
I'll also point out that it's not enough to just set -webkit-transform, as that only applies to webkit browsers. (Safari, Chrome, and Opera).  You will also need to set transform, and possibly also -moz-transform (firefox), -ms-transform (older IE), and -o-transform (older Opera).

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to have a boolean variable that indicates whether the mouse button is pressed down. And then adjust the rotation when the mouse moves.

```
var mouseDown = false;

var mouseButtonDown = function ()  {
    mouseDown = true;
} 

var mouseButtonUp = function ()  {
    mouseDown = false;
} 

var mouseMove = function (event) {
    if(mouseDown) {
        // get mouse coordinates and do rotation in jquery
   } 
}
```

The HTML:
    `<div onmousedown="mouseButtonDown" onmouseup="mouseButtonUp" onmousemove="mouseMove"></div>`

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I will see if I can create something with this and post it later on. :)